# How can I connect MySQL database on AWS to a lambda function without using a proxy

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, proxy, amazon-rds

I recently started using MySQL database on AWS on their free teir plan, I needed to connect to a lambda function so I can query data from the database through a proxy but I found out today that proxies are expensive. They have been responsible for 95% of my bills. I would like to access the database from lambda without a proxy. Please recommend an architecture that would work irrespective of security as I just need this for development and I use a better architecture during production.
Note that my database is allowed to communicate with the internet currently.

I used a proxies to connect lambda to MySQL database on AWS, I expect it to connect which I got but the proxy instance was too expensive for me so I would like connection without a proxy.

Comment: To connect to the RDS MySQL from an AWS Lambda function-- you do not need a proxy. You can use an API and write the connection class your self within the Lambda function. Ensure that the Lambda and database use the same secutiry group and set the inbound rules correctly.